# Analysis on the basis of comparison of 1st column of 1 files with 1st column of N number of files and print all files based of column 1

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have tab separated files and need to compare FILE_1 with N (10) files,  If the IDS of column 1 of first file match with the 1st column  of other files  print file 1  and value of the other files and if the IDS not presnt , first file and  NA to the column of other file. The example of the input and expected output file are given below.

**File 1**

```
A   1.1  0.2    0.3     1.1
B   1.3  2.1    0.2     0.1
C   1.8  0.5    2.6     3.8
D   1.2  5.1    1.7     0.1
E   1.9  4.3    2.8     1.6
F   1.6  5.1    2.9     7.1
G   1.8  2.8    0.3     3.7
H   1.9  3.6    3.7     0.1
I   1.0  2.4    4.9     2.5
J   1.1  2.0    0.1     0.4
```

**File 2**

```
A   d1   Q2    Q.3  E.1
B   a.3  S.1   A.2  R.1
J   a.1  2.0   031  4a4
```

**File 3**

```
E    1d9    4a3  2A8    1D6
F    1a.6   5a1  2W9    7Q1
J    QA8    1.8  0W3    3E7
```

**File 4**

```
F   1aa  5a   2Q    7WQ
G   ac   UW   0QW   3aQ
A   QQ   aws  AW    qw
```

I have tried the following code with two file initially but not getting the expected output

```
awk  '
        FILENAME == "File_2" {
                id = $0
                val[id] = $2","$3","$5
        }
        FILENAME == "File_1" {
                id = $1
                string
                if (val[id] == "") {
                        print id " " "NA"
                } else {
                        print id " " val[id]
                }
        }
' File_2 File_1
```

The above code print the File_2 and NA at the end of each line.

My expected output is looks like below

**Final Expected Output**

```
A  1.1  0.2  0.3  1.1  d1   Q2   Q.3  E.1  NA    NA   NA   NA   QQ   aws  AW   qw
B  1.3  2.1  0.2  0.1  a.3  S.1  A.2  R.1  NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
C  1.8  0.5  2.6  3.8  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
D  1.2  5.1  1.7  0.1  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
E  1.9  4.3  2.8  1.6  NA   NA   NA   NA   1d9   4a3  2A8  1D6  NA   NA   NA   NA
F  1.6  5.1  2.9  7.1  NA   NA   NA   NA   1a.6  5a1  2W9  7Q1  1aa  5a   2Q   7WQ
G  1.8  2.8  0.3  3.7  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   ac   UW   0QW  3aQ
H  1.9  3.6  3.7  0.1  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
I  1.0  2.4  4.9  2.5  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
J  1.1  2.0  0.1  0.4  a.1  2.0  031  4a4  QA8   1.8  0W3  3E7  NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: I'm presuming the leading spaces in Files 2 and 3 are typos; correct me if I am wrong (if I am, the workaround is easy).

Comment: ...and File 4  :-)

Comment: Yes, no space in the beginning of the files. I have corrected the files accordingly.

Comment: do the number of space at end matter?  my code presumes a certain number of spaces in input--is that ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays, `ARGIND`, and `gensub()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
ARGIND < (ARGC-1) {
    key = $1
    sub("[^"FS"]+"FS"?","")
    fileNrsKeys2vals[ARGIND][key] = $0
    fileNrs2numFlds[ARGIND] = NF
    next
}
{
    printf "%s", $0
    for ( fileNr=1; fileNr<ARGIND; fileNr++ ) {
        if ( fileNr in fileNrs2numFlds ) {
            numFlds = fileNrs2numFlds[fileNr]
            printf "%s", ( $1 in fileNrsKeys2vals[fileNr] ?
                OFS fileNrsKeys2vals[fileNr][$1] :
                gensub(/ /,OFS"NA","g",sprintf("%*s",numFlds,"")) )
        }
    }
    print ""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file3 file4 file1
A       1.1     0.2     0.3     1.1     d1      Q2      Q.3     E.1     NA      NA      NA      NA      QQ      aws     AW      qw
B       1.3     2.1     0.2     0.1     a.3     S.1     A.2     R.1     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
C       1.8     0.5     2.6     3.8     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
D       1.2     5.1     1.7     0.1     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
E       1.9     4.3     2.8     1.6     NA      NA      NA      NA      1d9     4a3     2A8     1D6     NA      NA      NA      NA
F       1.6     5.1     2.9     7.1     NA      NA      NA      NA      1a.6    5a1     2W9     7Q1     1aa     5a      2Q      7WQ
G       1.8     2.8     0.3     3.7     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      ac      UW      0QW     3aQ
H       1.9     3.6     3.7     0.1     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
I       1.0     2.4     4.9     2.5     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
J       1.1     2.0     0.1     0.4     a.1     2.0     031     4a4     QA8     1.8     0W3     3E7     NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: is array order guaranteed?

Comment: # of spaces is wrong if that matters

Comment: @Andrew array order is undefined, but the order I'm looping through the indices (`for ( fileNr=1; fileNr<ARGIND; fileNr++ )` to access the array elements is defined.

Comment: yes, between fields :-)

Comment: @Andrew OK, those are tabs and there's 1 between each pair of fields.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for this solution, but i have tried the code and found syntex error near  where "fileNrsKeys2vals"  used like in line 5, 14, and 15.  ( syntax error at or near [ )

Comment: Then you aren't using GNU awk as I said is required.

Comment: @EdMorton Better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75385039/445221

Comment: @konsolebox if you're going to claim that your solution is better than mine or any other then please edit your answer to explain in what way it's better because it's far from obvious why you would think so. Otherwise you may as well just delete your comment as it's totally subjective.

Comment: @EdMorton Actually storing each element individually and not using field replacement hacks is one thing. I did just notice your solution adapts with each file's field count but mine can easily implement it with a total fields per row counter and not use static values. E.g., `; i <= NF; ... ENDFILE { c += NF - 1 } ... ; j < c; ...`.

Comment: It can also be improved to even be more field count dynamic with `{ ... max = NF > max ? NF : max } ENDFILE { c += max - 1; max = 0 }`. These aren't explicitly required though.

Comment: @konsolebox please don't describe the differences in comments here where it's messy, could be missed by people interested in your answer, etc. just add it to your answer. As for "mine can easily implement..." and "It can also be improved..." - whatever either solution could be enhanced to do is easy, it's only software, I was just asking you to update your existing answer to tell us why you feel yours is better because so far I don't see why you'd think that and I expect others may also be confused by that claim.

Comment: Specifically in what ways are your answer faster, more robust, less memory intensive, easier to enhance, more portable, clearer or anything else concrete that you have in mind than mine thereby making it definitively better.

Answer (score 2):

This solution requires a " | sort" since awk arrays are not guaranteed to be in order.  It also is sensitive to the number of spaces immediately following the index letter ("A", "B", "C", etc.):

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat mergeLinesV0.awk
BEGIN {
 i1=1
 i2=1
 i3=1
 i4=1
} NR == FNR {
  ar1[i1]=$0
  i1=i1+1
  f1size=FNR
  next
}{
  f1done=1
} NR-f1size == FNR && f1done {
  ar2[i2]=$0
  i2=i2+1
  f2size=FNR
  next
}{
  f2done=1
} NR-f1size-f2size == FNR && f2done {
  ar3[i3]=$0
  i3=i3+1
  f3size=FNR
  next
}{
  f3done=1
} NR-f1size-f2size-f3size == FNR && f3done {
  ar4[i4]=$0
  i4=i4+1
  f4size=FNR
  next
} END {
  for(i1 in ar1){
    printf("%s   ", ar1[i1])
    found2=0
    for(i2 in ar2){
      if(substr(ar1[i1],1,1)==substr(ar2[i2],1,1)){
        printf("%s   ", substr(ar2[i2],5))
        found2=1
      }
    }
    if(!found2){
      printf("NA   NA   NA   NA   ")
    }
    found3=0
    for(i3 in ar3){
      if(substr(ar1[i1],1,1)==substr(ar3[i3],1,1)){
        printf("%s   ", substr(ar3[i3],5))
        found3=1
      }
    }
    if(!found3){
      printf("NA   NA   NA   NA   ")
    }
    found4=0
    for(i4 in ar4){
      if(substr(ar1[i1],1,1)==substr(ar4[i4],1,1)){
        printf("%s\n", substr(ar4[i4],5))
        found4=1
      }
    }
    if(!found4){
      printf("NA   NA   NA   NA\n")
    }
  }
}
```

```
Mac_3.2.57$awk -f mergeLinesV0.awk File1 File2 File3 File4 | sort
A   1.1  0.2    0.3     1.1   d1   Q2    Q.3  E.1   NA   NA   NA   NA   QQ   aws  AW    qw
B   1.3  2.1    0.2     0.1   a.3  S.1   A.2  R.1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
C   1.8  0.5    2.6     3.8   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
D   1.2  5.1    1.7     0.1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
E   1.9  4.3    2.8     1.6   NA   NA   NA   NA   1d9    4a3  2A8    1D6   NA   NA   NA   NA
F   1.6  5.1    2.9     7.1   NA   NA   NA   NA   1a.6   5a1  2W9    7Q1   1aa  5a   2Q    7WQ
G   1.8  2.8    0.3     3.7   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   ac   UW   0QW   3aQ
H   1.9  3.6    3.7     0.1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
I   1.0  2.4    4.9     2.5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
J   1.1  2.0    0.1     0.4   a.1  2.0   031  4a4   QA8    1.8  0W3    3E7   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat File1
A   1.1  0.2    0.3     1.1
B   1.3  2.1    0.2     0.1
C   1.8  0.5    2.6     3.8
D   1.2  5.1    1.7     0.1
E   1.9  4.3    2.8     1.6
F   1.6  5.1    2.9     7.1
G   1.8  2.8    0.3     3.7
H   1.9  3.6    3.7     0.1
I   1.0  2.4    4.9     2.5
J   1.1  2.0    0.1     0.4
Mac_3.2.57$cat File2
A   d1   Q2    Q.3  E.1
B   a.3  S.1   A.2  R.1
J   a.1  2.0   031  4a4
Mac_3.2.57$cat File3
E   1d9    4a3  2A8    1D6
F   1a.6   5a1  2W9    7Q1
J   QA8    1.8  0W3    3E7
Mac_3.2.57$cat File4
F   1aa  5a   2Q    7WQ
G   ac   UW   0QW   3aQ
A   QQ   aws  AW    qw
Mac_3.2.57$
```

Comment: `BEGIN{i1=1} ... {ar1[i1]=$0; i1=i1+1}` = `ar1[++i1]=$0`.

Comment: If you do `for(i1=1; i1 in ar1; i1++){` or `for(i1=1; i1<=f1size; i1++){` instead of `for(i1 in ar1){` then the order you access the array elements IS guaranteed as you're specifically telling awk the order to use.

Comment: Regarding `awk arrays are not guaranteed to be in order` - it'd be more correct to say something like "there is no inherent order to awk arrays and the order of visiting the elements by looping using the `in` operator is implementation-defined". Saying they aren't guaranteed to be in order implies there is some specific order that they should be in but they aren't but what order would that be - smallest to largest string? smallest to largest number? largest to smallest? first in? something else? The order you want to visit them just depends on your needs at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Given your 4 example files (as `file1.txt` .. `file4.txt`), here is a ruby that does that:

```
ruby -lne '
BEGIN{
    files={}
    seen=Set.new()
    data=Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new { |hh, kk| hh[kk] = [] } }
}
fields=$_.split(/\t/)
if $<.file.lineno==1; files[$<.file.path]=fields.length-1; end
seen<<fields[0]
data[fields[0]][files.keys.last]=fields[1..]
END{
    seen.each{|k| row=[k]
        files.each{|file, width|
            if data[k][file].empty?
                row.push(*["NA"]*width)
            else 
                row.push(*data[k][file])
            end
        }
        puts row.join("\t")
    }
}'  file?.txt
```

Prints:

```
A   1.1 0.2 0.3 1.1 d1  Q2  Q.3 E.1 NA  NA  NA  NA  QQ  aws AW  qw
B   1.3 2.1 0.2 0.1 a.3 S.1 A.2 R.1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
C   1.8 0.5 2.6 3.8 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
D   1.2 5.1 1.7 0.1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
E   1.9 4.3 2.8 1.6 NA  NA  NA  NA  1d9 4a3 2A8 1D6 NA  NA  NA  NA
F   1.6 5.1 2.9 7.1 NA  NA  NA  NA  1a.6    5a1 2W9 7Q1 1aa 5a  2Q  7WQ
G   1.8 2.8 0.3 3.7 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  ac  UW  0QW 3aQ
H   1.9 3.6 3.7 0.1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
I   1.0 2.4 4.9 2.5 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
J   1.1 2.0 0.1 0.4 a.1 2.0 031 4a4 QA8 1.8 0W3 3E7 NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

This produces exact expected output:

```
gawk '{
        a[$1] = 1
        for (i = 2; i <= 5; ++i)
            b[$1, (ARGIND - 1) * 4 + (i - 2)] = $i
    }
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc";
        for (i in a) {
            t = i
            for (j = 0; j < ARGIND * 4; ++j)
                t = t OFS (b[i, j] ? b[i, j] : "NA")
            print t
        }
    }' File_{1..4} | column -t
```